# Is there a way to show a 3x3 matrix of buttons in a PowerPoint ribbon?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, custom-ui

I'm working on a custom ribbon in PowerPoint using RibbonX with MS Custom UI.

I have a group called 'Arrange' and I'm trying to set up a menu on the ribbon that has 9 buttons (X) arranged in a 3x3 matrix like this:

```
  Menu Title
  1 2 3
  4 5 6
  7 8 9
```

The code I use to create the menu is:

```
    <menu id="mnuFileMenuXX" label="Filemenu" keytip="DL" supertip="Arrows.">
             <button id="button1" label="Button 1" imageMso="HappyFace" />
             <button id="button2" label="Button 2" imageMso="HappyFace" />
             <button id="button3" label="Button 3" imageMso="HappyFace" />
             <button id="button4" label="Button 4" imageMso="HappyFace" />
             <button id="button5" label="Button 5" imageMso="HappyFace" />
             <button id="button6" label="Button 6" imageMso="HappyFace" />                 
             <button id="button7" label="Button 7" imageMso="HappyFace" />
             <button id="button8" label="Button 8" imageMso="HappyFace" />
             <button id="button9" label="Button 9" imageMso="HappyFace" />
    </menu>
```

When I try arrange the buttons, nothing seems to work: boxes, separators.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help understand what you're after if you posted a diagram of some sort, and also show what you're getting from the existing RibbonX above.

Answer (score 0):

This XML is working here to display a 3x3 grid of small icons:

```
<group
    <box
        boxStyle="horizontal"
        id="BoxParagraph1">
        <control
            idMso="AlignLeft"
            visible="true"/>
        <control
            idMso="AlignCenter"
            visible="true"/>
        <control
            idMso="AlignRight"
            visible="true"/>
    </box>
    <box
        boxStyle="horizontal"
        id="BoxParagraph2">
        <control
            idMso="IndentIncrease"
            visible="true"/>
        <control
            idMso="IndentDecrease"
            visible="true"/>
        <control
            idMso="TextAlignGallery"
            showLabel="false"
            visible="true"/>
    </box>
    <box
        boxStyle="horizontal"
        id="BoxParagraph3">
        <button
            id="SetMarginsToZero"
            imageMso="TableCellAlignTopLeft"
            onAction="Set_Margin_Zero"
            screentip="Reove margin of selected shapes"
            showImage="true"
            showLabel="false"
            getEnabled="ShapeButtons_GetEnabled"/>
        <button
            id="SetMarginsToStandard"
            imageMso="TableCellCustomMarginsDialog"
            onAction="Set_Margin_Standard"
            screentip="Set margin of selected shapes to standard"
            showImage="true"
            showLabel="false"
            getEnabled="ShapeButtons_GetEnabled"/>
        <button
            id="SetSpaceBeforeAfterZero"
            imageMso="ParagraphSpacingAfter"
            onAction="Set_Paragraph_Space_Zero"
            screentip="Remove paragraph spacing"
            showImage="true"
            showLabel="false"
            getEnabled="ShapeButtons_GetEnabled"/>
    </box>
</group>
```

Comment: Thank you @john.  The boxes don't seem to be working within the menu... any thoughts?

Comment: Do you mean I can nest a group within a menu?

Comment: A menu is a list of names that always appear in a single column. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-customui/0243b261-903e-43d9-8e8b-43f66ea0bcaf You can't create a 3x3 arrangement in a menu. My listing shows how to arrange items in a 3x3 grid, but it's not a menu.